# Laravel dusk if browser->assertSee then do this

Tags: laravel, laravel-dusk

Is there a way to proceed with a test even if assertSee returns with an error.

This is my current code:

```
$browser->visit('https://urltotest.co.uk/find-an-engineer/')
        ->type("EngineerId", $engineerId)
        ->click('#checkEngineer');

$test = $browser->assertSee("Engineer cannot be found");
```

What I would like to be able to do is go:

```
if ($test == false) {
    return false;  
} else {
    return $browser->text('.engineer-search-results-container .search-result .col-md-8 .row .col-xs-10 h3');
}
```

But when the assertSee fails all I get back is:

```
Did not see expected text [Engineer cannot be found] within element [body].
```

As an exception. Any way I can proceed if it can't find that element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to achieve this using a `try catch` to catch the exception:

```
try {
    $browser->assertSee("Engineer cannot be found");
} catch(\Exception $e) {
    return false;
}
```

To note, I do not know if there is a method such as `$browser->fail()` (like phpunit's `$this->fail()`) which will fail the test for you.